# Concatenating two tensors with different dimensions in Pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch

Is it possible to concatenate two tensors with different dimensions without using for loop.

e.g. Tensor 1 has dimensions (15, 200, 2048) and Tensor 2 has dimensions (1, 200, 2048). Is it possible to concatenate 2nd tensor with 1st tensor along all the 15 indices of 1st dimension in 1st Tensor (Broadcast 2nd tensor along 1st dimension of Tensor 1 while concatenating along 3rd dimension of 1st tensor)? The resulting tensor should have dimensions (15, 200, 4096).

Is it possible to accomplish this without for loop ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You could do the broadcasting manually (using [`Tensor.expand()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/tensors.html#torch.Tensor.expand)) before the concatenation (using [`torch.cat()`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/torch.html#torch.cat)):

```python
import torch

a = torch.randn(15, 200, 2048)
b = torch.randn(1, 200, 2048)

repeat_vals = [a.shape[0] // b.shape[0]] + [-1] * (len(b.shape) - 1)
# or directly repeat_vals = (15, -1, -1) or (15, 200, 2048) if shapes are known and fixed...
res = torch.cat((a, b.expand(*repeat_vals)), dim=-1)
print(res.shape)
# torch.Size([15, 200, 4096])
```

Comment: What is the difference between `Tensor.expand()` and `Tensor.repeat()`? Is it that `expand` does not allocate new memory, but `repeat` does? Since we will be manipulating the expanded dimensions differently, is `repeat` better since it allocates memory upfront?